# How can we measure meaning in both our organization and competition?

Tags: research, mental-models, design-frameworks, ux-research

This question is about **Meaningful UX** or the **Meaning Model**. It's not about meaning in the sense of dialectics and semiotics. For those who don't know, please see http://nathan.com/making-meaning/

**Consider the following image:**

[image]

It's evident that we could measure corporate and team priorities through *ad hoc* KPIs, and we may measure customers' priorities through qualitative surveys. Sort of.

But even then, I find almost impossible to measure all 15 core meanings on all three of these dimensions, let alone doing it with competitors.

So teh question is:

**Is there a better way or an established framework for this purpose?** More importantly, **how can we measure competitors' priorities?**

Comment: To the question of how to measure competitor priorities, I assume you would have to know what they are in the first place? And also assume that they are aligned in the organisation to start with.

Comment: Exactly, how to know and measure them since unless someone from the competitors side provides teh info, it seems very difficult if not impossible